# Rebuild tibble under condition

Tags: r

My Tibble:

```
df1 <- tibble(a = c("123*", "123", "124", "678*", "678", "679", "677"))

# A tibble: 7 x 1
  a    
  <chr>
1 123* 
2 123  
3 124  
4 678* 
5 678  
6 679  
7 677
```

What it should become:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  a     b    
  <chr> <chr>
1 123   124  
2 678   679  
3 678   677
```

The values with the stars refer to the following values with no stars, until a new value with a star comes and so on.

Each value with a star should go to the first column, the other values (except the ones that are identical to the values with a star, except the star) should go to the second column. If one value with a star is followed by several values, they should still be linked to eachother, so the values in the first column are duplicated to keep the connection.

I know how to filter and bring the values in each column, but not sure how i would keep the connection.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `tidyverse`.  Create a grouping column based on the occurence of `*` in 'a', extract the numeric part with `parse_number`, get the `distinct` rows, grouped by 'grp', create a new column with the `first` value of 'b'

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>%
    transmute(grp = cumsum(str_detect(a, fixed("*"))), 
       b = readr::parse_number(a)) %>% 
    distinct(b, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
    group_by(grp) %>% 
    mutate(a = first(b)) %>%
    slice(-1) %>% 
    ungroup %>%
    select(a, b)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 2
      a     b
  <dbl> <dbl>
1   123   124
2   678   679
3   678   677
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one base R option -

- Using `cumsum` and `grepl` we split the data on occurrence of `*`.
- In each group, we drop the values which are similar to the star values and create a dataframe with two columns.
- Finally, combine the list of dataframes in one combined dataframe.

```
result <- do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df1, 
             cumsum(grepl('*', df1$a, fixed = TRUE))), function(x) {
  a <- x[[1]]
  a[1] <- sub('*', '', a[1], fixed = TRUE)
  data.frame(a = a[1], b = a[a != a[1]])
}))
rownames(result) <- NULL
result

#    a   b
#1 123 124
#2 678 679
#3 678 677
```